# Sending HTML as javascript variable through getJSON doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I've seen some questions about sending HTML data *from* PHP *to* an HTML page, but this question is actually for the contrary (I can get HTML from PHP fine with json_encode).

A small snippet of code that explains most of it:

```
savePage = function() {
 var pagecontents = $("#editcontents").val();
 log("Attempting to save page...");
 $.getJSON(docTools+"?jsoncallback=?",{action:'update', loginCookie:loginCookie, page:thisFile, newdata:pagecontents}, function(data) {
  if(data.response[0].answer === 'true') {
   log('Page'+thisFile+' was saved correctly: '+data.response[0].details);
   $("#editcontents, #saveedit, #canceledit").remove();
   $("#bodycontents").html(pagecontents);
  } else {
   log('Failed to save page. Error (' + data.response[0].errorcode + ') : ' + data.response[0].errormessage);
  }
 });
}
```

FYI: log just does console.log if it exists.

So basically what happens here is that the **pagecontents** variable contains HTML data, all within a `<body>` tag (meaning no header information if that matters). However, when I actually call this function, the log() function works fine... but the getJSON() never completes (actually, as far as I can tell it never makes it to my PHP server).

If I replace **pagecontents** with just a standard string, it works fine.

Do I need to do something akin to json_encode from javascript before sending? Something that would convert everything to html entities?

**--Edit--**

So I just discovered the "Net" tab in Firebug and it's showing me something I hadn't realized: it shows the GET request with all the proper data... But the server returns a 404. I don't know how that could happen since the PHP file is the same one that I grab stuff from 5 seconds before.

Also, even though I tried to change .getJSON() with .post(...,'json') , Firebug is still showing a GET request, not a POST, so it's got me even more confused now.

Comment: How long is the actual string? JSONP is a GET request, so there are limits you'll run into there.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting to, you may be on to something. In this instance the code comes up to 3632 characters, which is fairly long (and not the longest I will have to send). Since getJSON doesn't do post, I may have to dig deeper...

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to use `encodeURIComponent` since all of that data is going to get shipped in the URL string (the length might be an issue as well).

Comment: This is handled by jQuery internally when you pass the data argument as an object :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.post {(docTools+"?jsoncallback=?",{action:'update', loginCookie:loginCookie, page:thisFile, newdata:pagecontents}, function(data) {
  if(data.response[0].answer === 'true') {
   log('Page'+thisFile+' was saved correctly: '+data.response[0].details);
   $("#editcontents, #saveedit, #canceledit").remove();
   $("#bodycontents").html(pagecontents);
  } else {
   log('Failed to save page. Error (' + data.response[0].errorcode + ') : ' + data.response[0].errormessage);
  }
 },
  'json'
);
```

Comment: You can't post to another domain and see the response...it's prohibited by the same origin policy, and why JSONP exists :)

Comment: @Nick I did not realise it was a cross-domain ajax issue.

Comment: Look for the callback specified in the URL, that's usually the tale-tale sign :)